# Output units without multiply character?

Tags: java, units-of-measurement, jscience

I am using the awesome JScience library to convert units. What is bothering me:

The output of for example `WATT.times(HOUR)` is `W·h`.

What I want to output is just `Wh`. Is it possible to change the output for all units without implementing an own `UnitFormat`? I know I could label all these units but that is a lot of work, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found no JScience/UnitsOfMeasurement based solution so I did it by myself:

```
public static String formatUnit(final Unit unit) {
  return unit.toString().replace("·", "");
}
```